# Paperclip4 & Rails4 background job on CREATE+UPDATE actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, background-process, resque

I'm trying to figure how to use paperclip with background job especially on update.

**WHAT I WANT : A 2 steps update 1st assign the original pic, 2nd generate styles in background job**

While updating User parameters :

> - I have a file on S3 (uploaded with direct_upload)
> - I attach this file (url) to my document.attachment model before paperclip does its process
> - Paperclip uses the url and generate original file (copy the file to the paperclip folder)
>
>   - Do not process the styles yet
> - Once the original is ok, I want to reprocess the others styles (:medium, :thumb)
> - Isolate the reprocess (or global process) inside a background job (Resque) for efficiency)

**WHAT I TRIED**

> - Successfully assign the file from S3 url, so I wont detail it here
>
>   - All styles are generated from the S3 one
> - Block paperclip post_process
> - add the reprocess background job call insite the controller after if @user.save, which generate all the style on .save, then reprocess them all with @user.panorama.attachment.reprocess!...

**WHERE I FAIL**

> - No success on style reprocess isolation (background job) on update action:
>
>   - Infinite loop because paperclip restart a update after reprocess since file changed
> - Tried both model and controller way, using a boolean "process" but still bloqued on a loop

```
after_update :reprocess_styles
before_post_process :stop_process

    def stop_process
      false #stop paperclip styles the post processing
    end

    def reprocess_styles
      self.reprocess! :medium, :thumb #lauch the post process
      self.save(validate: false)
    end
```

The fact that its an on update action brings me to a loop that I can't manage properly.

I either have an infinite loop that reprocess the styles again an again, or no style at all.

Thank you very much for any help.

**MODEL**

```
class Panorama < Document
  attr_reader :attachement_remote_url
  before_create :attachment_remote_url
  before_update :attachment_remote_url

  # after_create :process_styles
  after_update :process_styles

  has_attached_file :attachment,
  styles: { medium: "1000x1000#", thumb: "160x160#" },
  convert_options: { medium: "-quality 75 -strip",
                     thumb: "-quality 75 -strip" },
  default_url: ":parent_type/:class/:style/missing.png",
  path: "/documents/:parent_type/:id_partition/:class/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment :attachment,
  content_type: { content_type: ["image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"] },
  size: { less_than: 10.megabyte }

  before_post_process :stop_process

  def stop_process
    if !self.process && self.attachment_changed?
      # self.process = true #loop...
      false
    end
  end

  def attachment_remote_url
    self.attachment = URI.parse("path to my Amazon S3 file")
  end

  def process_styles
    if !self.process
      puts self.inspect
      # self.process = false #loop...
      self.attachment.reprocess! :medium, :thumb
      self.save(validate: false)
    end
  end

  def attachment_changed?
    self.attachment_file_name_changed? or
    self.attachment_content_type_changed? or
    self.attachment_file_size_changed? or
    self.attachment_updated_at_changed?
  end
end
```

Comment: Doing the same thing and stuck at the same point. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it with Sidekiq background job:

```
# models/vignette.rb
class Profile < Document # I use polymorphism
  has_attached_file :attachment,
    styles: { square: "" },
    convert_options: { square: "-gravity north -thumbnail 300x300^ -extent 300x300+0+0 -quality 75" },
    default_url: ":parent_type/:class/:style/missing.png",
    path: "/documents/:parent_type/:id_partition/:class/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment :attachment,
    content_type: { content_type: ["image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"] },
    size: { less_than: 1.megabyte }

  before_post_process :stop_process
  after_commit :process_styles

  def stop_process
    if !self.process and self.attachment_changed?
      self.process = true
      false
    end
  end

  def process_styles
    DocumentStyleProcess.perform_async(self.id) if self.process
  end

  def attachment_changed?
    self.attachment_file_size_changed? or
    self.attachment_file_name_changed? or
    self.attachment_content_type_changed? or
    self.attachment_updated_at_changed?
  end
end


# workers/document_style_process.rb
class DocumentStyleProcess
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :first
  def perform document_id
    document = Document.find(document_id)
    document.attachment.assign(document.attachment)
    document.process = false
    document.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

Note that document.process is a dedidacted column with boolean type.
Hope it helps.